# ReactiveForms refresh page after submitting in Angular CLI

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am following the tutorial:
 https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/10/29/angular-7-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial

and write a login form according to this by using ReactiveFormsModule in Angular 7
However, after I click on submit with wrong information I just see alert at top for a second and page refreshes itself. I searched a lot about this topic and changing button type does not help.

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <div>
  <h2 align="center">Login</h2>
  <form [formGroup]="loginForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">E-mail</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="email" class="form-control" placeholder="your_email@example.com" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.email.errors }" />
      <div *ngIf="submitted && f.email.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
        <div *ngIf="f.email.errors">Invalid e-mail</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" formControlName="password" placeholder="******" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.password.errors }" />
      <div *ngIf="submitted && f.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
        <div *ngIf="f.password.errors" >Invalid password</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button  (click)="onSubmit()" [disabled]="loading || !loginForm.controls.email.value || !loginForm.controls.password.value" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
      <img *ngIf="loading" class="pl-2" src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
    </div>

    <a routerLink="/register" class="go-register">Do you need an account?</a>
  </form>

</div>
```

and TypeScript file:

```
import { Component, OnInit , OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { AlertService } from '../services/alert.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  loginForm: FormGroup;
  loading = false;
  submitted = false;
  returnUrl: string;
  error = '';

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private alertService: AlertService
  ) { }


  ngOnInit() {

    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.email, Validators.required]],
      password: ['', [Validators.pattern('^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9]).{6,}$'),
        Validators.minLength(6),
        Validators.required]]
    });

    // reset login status
    this.authenticationService.logout();

    // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
    this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.returnUrl || '/';
  }

  // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
  get f() { return this.loginForm.controls; }

  onSubmit() {


    this.submitted = true;

    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    this.loading = true;
    this.authenticationService.login(this.f.email.value, this.f.password.value)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
        },
        error => {
          this.error = error;
          // alert(error);
          this.alertService.error(error);
          this.loading = false;
        });
  }
}
```

I debug my code and I guess problem is about HTML but I cannot resolve.

Also, I tried add event.preventDefault() and (ngSubmit), none of them helped me.

I am open for any ideas...

Answer (score -2):

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#saving-form-data

You have to use ngSubmit...

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```

Then the default behaviour is disabled and angular handles it.